# Linux/Shell slicing a large text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Given

File1

```
uniquename1:somethinguseless:somethinguseless:uniquekey1
uniquename2:somethinguseless:somethinguseless:uniquekey2
uniquename3:somethinguseless:somethinguseless:uniquekey3
```

File2

```
uniquekey1:hello
uniquekey2:apple
uniquekey3:hello
```

I wish to make a method that basically does this

```
$ command uniquename2
apple
$ command uniquename1
hello
$ command uniquename3
hello
```

So given a uniquename from file1 it will use its key from file2 to get what it's link to. If it doesn't find uniquename do nothing.

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
$ grep -i 'uniquename1' | (not sure how to slice the line with regex "*:*:*") | grep $thisline file2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cut` utility was designed for this type of data:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY=$(grep -i -e "^$1:" file1.txt | cut -d ':' -f 4)
grep -e "^$KEY" file2.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Comment: this almost works but one problem was, if the beginning of the unique name were similar then it would grab that. for example: "aaabc123:...." and "abc123". If I wanted to grab abc123 it would grab aaabc123 instead

Comment: I modified the first grep command to match from the beginning of the line to the first colon. I modified the second grep to assume a colon at the end of the key and match from the beginning of the line to the end of the key.

Comment: It recently occurred to me that the :somethinguseless:somethinguseless: may contain ':' which gives me the wrong output for some of them. It does however work for most all not having ':'. uniquename/uniquekey don't contain ':' though.

Comment: Without a better description of your data, we are just guessing at the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` makes this relatively easy. For example:

```
$ sed -n "/$(sed -n '/uniquename2/s/.*[:]//p' file1)/s/.*[:]//p" file2
apple
```

or

```
$ sed -n "/$(sed -n '/uniquename3/s/.*[:]//p' f1)/s/.*[:]//p" f2
hello
```

You are simply using the *command substitution* `$(sed -n '/uniquename3/s/.*[:]//p' f1)` to get the `uniquekey` from `uniquename` trimming the leading portion of the line, and then doing the same thing to the result to get the wanted string with `sed -n "/$(command)/s/.*[:]//p"` using double-quotes on the outer to allow the *command substitution* to expand.

The form of the basic `sed` command used is the normal substitution `s/find/replace` with a leading pattern match for a total

```
sed '/match/s/find/replace/`
```

The `-n` suppresses normal printing of pattern space and the `p` at the end, causes it to print when the match and substitution succeed.

**If `uniquename` or `uniquekey` Contain regex Characters**

Given your comment about your actual file returning an error, it appears each `uniquename` or `uniquekey` in your actual files contain characters that can be interpreted as regular expressions. In that case, a GNU `awk` solution using the `FILENAME` variable to extract the needed information from each file based on the fields separated by `':'` should work, e.g.

```
$ awk -F: -v name=uniquename2 '
    FILENAME == "file1" { $1 == name && key = $NF } 
    FILENAME == "file2" { if ($1 == key) print $NF }
' file1 file2
apple
```

Let me know if you have problems there. Also, if you can post some actual examples (say 10 lines each) of your `file1` and `file2`, that would help.

Comment: When I try it with a bigger file I get this: "sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown command: `m'"

Comment: Do you have DOS line ending in one of the files? (there is no `'m'` in the command)

Comment: @aki Also, what can `somethinguseless:somethinguseless` actually be? If there are characters that are meaningful as a `regex`, then I can see that causing problems.

Comment: nevermind, they can be anything. Is there a way to get the tail of a line then :/?

Comment: Ok, give me a second to think about how to remove any special meaning. I'm not sure, if that is the case, that anything interpreting a regex will work.

Comment: Also the uniquekey doesn't have a ':' in it as a symbol. Uniquekey is only numbers and alphabetical characters

Answer (score 1):

Here an `awk` script that scan both files only once. Unlike the nested `grep` solution doing `uniqueId * (uniqueId - 1)` file scans.

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN {FS=":"} # field separator is :
FNR == NR && $1 == keyArg {id = $NF} # find the id in first file
FNR == NR {next} # continue scanning first file
$1 == id {print $2} # find the id in second file and print its 2nd field value
```

Execution:

```
 awk -v keyArg="uniquename2" -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: `FNR == NR && $1 == keyArg {id = $NF; next}` should be `FNR == NR {if ($1 == keyArg) id = $NF; next}` so the `next` applies to all lines of file1, not just the 1 line where $1 matches keyArg.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is either this:

```
$ awk -v tgt='uniquename2' -F':' 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2; next} $1==tgt{print map[$NF]}' file2 file1
apple
```

or almost (see my comment under it) [what @DudiBoy posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56714875/1745001).